# New tab browser URL selenium C#

Tags: selenium

I am writing UI test cases. I have a scenario that, when I click a link it will open in a new tab. I want to get the new tab browser URl?

I am using,

```
  string URL = WebDriver.Url;
```

But this gives me the main tab URL. How do I get the new tab URL?

Comment: Try switching the driver focus to the new tab and then perform `string URL = WebDriver.Url;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var browserTabs = new List<string>(Driver.WindowHandles);

var newTab = browserTabs[1];
var yourUrl = Driver.SwitchTo().Window(newTab).Url;
```